# "For" and "in" with present perfect tense

Tags: prepositions, present-perfect, aspect

Consider:

> a. I have learned English for 6 months.
>
> b. I have learned English in 6 months.

Are the two sentences above grammatically correct?

Do they carry the same meaning?

Answer (score 3):

*Learn* is what linguists call a 'telic' verb: one which in its basic use implies that its action moves toward and achieves a final goal, a 'change of state'. In the case of *learn* the 'change of state' is from ignorance to knowledge.

> I have learned English for 6 months.

The construction ***for*** TIMESPAN is typically used with a 'non-telic' verb: one which in its basic use designates an activity which does not have a final 'goal' but continues indefinitely: *I have lived here for six months*. When a *for TIMESPAN* is used with a telic verb it usually signifies that the action was carried out repeatedly. For instance, *She has written novels for ten years* is taken to mean that she wrote a novel, and then wrote another novel, and then wrote . . . and so forth.

That is probably not what you mean. You may have learned a great deal of English, but you have not learned the entire language. (Neither has anyone else, including me!) I suspect what you want to say is that you have ***studied*** English for six months—*study* is a non-telic verb signifying the activity of attempting to acquire knowledge, not successfully completing the attempt.

> I have learned English in 6 months.

***In*** TIMESPAN is something quite different: it designates the time it took you to complete an action, and is used only with telic verbs. You might for instance say *In six months I have learned enough English to ask intelligent questions*. As before, however, *I have learned English* without any qualification implies that you have mastered the entire language; it would be quite extraordinary to achieve that in six months, or even six decades!

Comment: "I have been learning English for six months"

Comment: @TerryWendt Yes: the progressive construction characterizes the action of even a telic verb as 'imperfect', unfinished, so it recategorizes *learn* as a non-telic activity.

Comment: In your *She has written novels for ten years*, does the plural form of *novel* decide the verb *write* is being used with a telic sense? I think one could keep writing a novel on and on.

Comment: @KinzleB Yes, indeed; though if *novel* were singular it would have to be determinate, and *write* would have to be recast: we wouldn't say *She has written that novel* or *She wrote that novel* "for ten years", it would have to be *She has been writing* or *She was writing* (or *She kept writing*).

Comment: Oh, this is absolutely new to me! I guess even my college professors wouldn't know about it. BTW, I borrowed McCawley from our national library. It's a really nice read. I'm gonna digitalize it and make a searchable version. I think the textile of my thinking has been changing a lot since I read Bas Aarts, H&P, etc. Thanks for your recommendation!

Answer (score -1):

for indicates time up to now according to its usage. but we can't see it with in.we can tell I was a student in 1995. if it gives a same meaning we can use I was a student for 1995. I think every thing has a usage.